# Recaptcha Not woking? Undefined index: recaptcha_challenge_field

Tags: php, yii

I have try many times but the recaptcha still doesn't work and always say Undefined index: recaptcha_challenge_field

But i was followed the instruction ...

Hare is my coding ... i using yii framework

IN php :

```
<?php

 <form id="registration" method="post" action="<?php echo Yii::app()->getHomeUrl(); ?>?r=Register/Registration">

//some input detail


//at the bottom the recaptcha code
    <?php
            require_once('captcha/recaptchalib.php');
            $publickey = "the_public_key"; // you got this from the signup page
            echo recaptcha_get_html($publickey);
            ?>

</form>
?>
```

THEN in the controller

```
public function actionRegistration(){


        require_once('captcha/recaptchalib.php');
        $privatekey = "the_private_key";
        $resp = recaptcha_check_answer ($privatekey,
                            $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"],
                            $_POST["recaptcha_challenge_field"],
                            $_POST["recaptcha_response_field"]);

        if (!$resp->is_valid) {
        // What happens when the CAPTCHA was entered incorrectly
        die ("The reCAPTCHA wasn't entered correctly. Go back and try it again." .
            "(reCAPTCHA said: " . $resp->error . ")");
        } else {
            echo "Your code here to handle a successful verification";
        }

}
```

Any suggestion to make it working in this yii project?

Answer (score 0):

The `$_POST` variable probably does not have what you are looking for.

When you have this kind of problem, the best thing  to do is to call `var_dump()` to see what **is** being added to `$_POST`, for example:

```
require_once('captcha/recaptchalib.php');
$privatekey = "the_private_key";
//var dump for debugging:
echo '<pre>';
var_dump($_POST);
echo '</pre>';
exit;

//now the rest of your code, as before:
$resp = recaptcha_check_answer ($privatekey,
                        $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"],
                        $_POST["recaptcha_challenge_field"],
                        $_POST["recaptcha_response_field"]);
```

Comment: all it show just input detail doesn't show anything about capcha...and i gonna do what ?

Comment: well it means your captcha data is **not** getting submitted to your script.